# Alarm clock and ERROR: timed out in Android Viewer Client

Tags: android, python, time, adb, androidviewclient

I have simple test on AVC in python, that unlock device and launch application. This test runs in the infinity loop and it runs normally, but after some time (hour or two) I got an errors 'Alarm clock' and 'ERROR: timed out'. It looks like:

```
start: 1401863215000
ERROR: timed out
sleep
Alarm clock
parser: 1401863215000
```

where start, sleep and parser messages is my prints:

```
    print ("start: " + start)
    os.system('python satest.py > _LOGS/launch_log' + start + '.txt')

    print ("sleep")
    time.sleep(5)

    print ("parser: " + start)
    os.system('python parser.py')
```

Can someone suggest where an error could be? additional info is on [github](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/issues/81#issuecomment-44966873)

here is one of my methods:

```
def verify_view(view, delay, it):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    s = 0
    for counter in range(1,it):
        vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit())
        view_object = vc.findViewWithText(view)
        if (view_object is None):
            print("VERIFY: view - " + view + " not found")
            s = 2
            time.sleep(delay)
        else:
            print("VERIFY: view - " + view + " exists")
            s = 1
            break
    stop = datetime.datetime.now()
    global rest
    rest = stop - start
    print("VERIFY: verification time is: " + str(rest) + " seconds")
    if (s == 0):
        print("VERIFY: TEST ERROR, debug param 's' ==  " + str(s))
        return False
    if (s == 1):
        print("VERIFY: verification finished successfully, text - '" + view + "' was found")
        return True
    else:
        print("VERIFY: verification failed, there are no text - '" + view + "'")
        return False
```

Comment: Connecting to a device in a loop doesn't seem right. Why are you doing it?

Comment: I can move connection outside, but should it fix this issue?

Comment: Try it and tell me...

Comment: I got the same result: ERROR: timed out , ERROR: Offending XML:

Comment: Help us help you. Try to simplify your script until you have the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem. Describe your environment so others can reproduce it too. Without these pieces is very unlikely somebody could help you.